# Sending a response via ajax but continuing php script

Tags: php, ajax

I have a script that uploads a file to my webserver via http, what i need is the server to send a response to the http post but then continue to run some commands.

For example

file is posted via http

Server saves the file the inserts data into the database and sends a response to the http.

But i need the server to continue to run after the response and continue running some editing on the file.

example php

```
function uploadFile(){

$imageName = $tmpname . '.jpg';
            move_uploaded_file ($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"], $targetDir . $imageName);

$data = Array('ALL THE DATABASE DATE')
$returnid = $this->uploader_model->addData($data);  

//I NEED IT TO RETURN THIS TO THE AJAX HTTP REQUEST
            echo json_encode(array(
                    'returned' => 'Successfully uploaded..',
                    'id' => $returnid
            ));

//I NOW NEED IT TO KEEP RUNNNG SOME EDITING ON THE IMAGE HERE IE..
shell_exec(" run some image editing here 2>&1");

}
```

I have seen ignore user abort like

```
ignore_user_abort(1); // run script in background 
set_time_limit(0); // run script forever
```

but does this mean the script will just run forever and crash the server if it is getting multiple requests? just a bit confused on how to use this function correctly in this scenario

Any help please

Comment: Why don't you do it before echo?

Comment: Its just a example script its for user experience they only need one image to start with then a response then the others can be edited in the background before they are needed it would save at least 1 minute of the user waiting for a response, this way it would take 20 seconds

Comment: I haven't done anything like this before since web infrastructure delivers you a signal based connection. You send something, you receive something. I'm not sure, but [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) might worth looking.

Answer (score 0):

Your script won't run forever unless you make it, e.g. by using an infinite loop. Having said that, that's not necessarily a good way to go about it.

To ensure the best user experience, you should make sure your script executes quickly by deferring any time-consuming tasks. For example, you could create a task queue and run the queued tasks with cron.

Alternatively, if you do decide to use the solution you described in your question, you may be better off running that with AJAX *after* a file has been successfully uploaded. AJAX requests may be terminated when the user navigates off the webpage, so you'd still need to make sure the server continues executing your script.

BTW, You should also run flush() if you actually want to send something to the client.